# How do I filter out records with more than one matching key in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have two BMWs and two Mercedes and one Kia. They are in a MySQL table with car_id and brand.I want to know how what brands of car I only have one of. So what I expect returned is one record in this case with a brand of 'Kia' I don't want BMW or Mercedes to show up at all.

**Edit**

I've over simplified my problem. Sorry about that. So here's the real deal. I have a table with sid and hid. sid is unique but hid is not. I need to count the number of unique hid's. To do that I've done,

```
select count(distinct hid) from table
```

To count the full number of records there are I just looked at the number of rows returned from

```
select * from table
```

Now, given that hid should only appear either once or twice and given that I know how many times there are duplicate hid's, I should be able to add half of the number of duplicate hids on to the number of unique hids and end up with the full number of records. However, I'm off by 7. So to try to find the difference I tried to do...

```
select * from ( 
 select distinct hid from table group by hid
  union
 select hid from table group by hid) group by hid
```

thinking that this would return me any hids that are showing in the second query that are not in the first. It doesn't though and I'm pretty much stuck on where to go from here. Is there a way to take the two queries I have and get a diff on the hids?

I don't mean difference as in "subtract the total hids from the unique hids" I mean diff as in what hids are in the total that are not showing in the unique for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.hid
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.hid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Previously:

```
  SELECT t.brand
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.brand
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: I think your solution would work great if I hadn't over simplified the real problem I'm having :-\ Sorry about that. Please see the edit.

Comment: I don't want the difference between the total and the unique. I want the actual hids that are in the total but are not showing in unique.

Comment: @docgnome: Not showing in the unique?  That reads to me as those which are duplicated...

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me. But when I try to verify that I'm getting the correct number, as I said, I keep coming up short by 7. Where are the other 7? I have no idea and it's driving me up a wall. So I'm trying to find these 7 but I can't seem to do that.

Comment: @docgnome: A difference of seven doesn't mean there are 7 duplicated hid values - one could be duplicated 6 times, and another only twice.  The query to look at those with more than one should count to equal the number missing.

Comment: It didn't though. I think the simplest solution at this point is to nuke the servers from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. -_- I'm about to just bag it. The query I have to count unique hids makes logical sense so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @docgnome: Sorry - I can only go by the information provided.  Assuming the dataset is small enough & you published the mysqldump file for the table -- I'd be willing to load it into MySQL & test.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but it is unfortunataly sensitive data. I think what you've answered solves the problem but there is something else going on that I can't seem to find that is causing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* as though you want a single query which will return both the total number of records *and* the number of `hid`s that only occur once - if so, try:

```
select sum(count_hid) total_count, 
       sum(case count_hid when 1 then 1 else 0 end) singles_count
from
(select count(*) count_hid
 from your_table
 group by hid) sq
```